# Can't find the findViewById function

Tags: android, eclipse, findviewbyid

I'm an Android newbie working with the Eclipse IDE and the Android SDK. Anyway, I've watched a few tutorials and I can't seem to be able to call the findViewById() function.

I would appreciate if you could instruct me how to use it, if it's a method of a static class or something else.

Thanks, I'm sure this won't be a problem for the more advanced users!

---

Well the in response to the comments I'm trying to use it in an Activity.
Here's the code in there:

```
package tk.quiero.test1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Where exactly am I *supposed* to use it?
Thanks

Comment: can you paste the code where you are trying to use findViewbyId? Are you using this in an Activity or Fragment?

Comment: Do you tried read the android documentation?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)

Comment: I pasted the code, and I will take the look at that link :)

Comment: @user3750762 Where you are supposed to use it depends entirely on what you want to do. The only constraint I can think of is that you'd have to call it after `setContentView()` is called. Besides that, just call `findViewById(R.id.id_of_thing_you_want)` at any point in your code and it should work.

Comment: Could you give me a simple example in that code Nathan? Sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` is defined in the Activity class, so it sounds like you're trying to call this from outside of the Activity.  If so, you should post what exactly you're trying to do because there are ways of doing this, but there's also a high likelihood that there's a cleaner or easier way than resolving UI elements outside of the Activity

Comment: It's worth noting that it's also defined in `View`.

Comment: findViewById is not from a activity is from a View.

Comment: @user3586222 It's defined in both Activity and View, and most often used by new Android developers in the Activity (in View, it's mostly used for complex containers/composite views...someone posting that they're brand new to Android is most likely not doing that).  Here's a link to Activity.findViewById as a token of my appreciation for your downvote:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29

Comment: Is correct, the activity can use findViewById() because is basically a View.

Comment: @user3586222 No, that is blatantly false. `Activity` doesn't extend `View` in any way. `Activity` can contain views but it certainly is not one itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.xxxxx)
}
```

replace xxxxx with the id that you've defined in your xml...which should look like @+id/xxxxx

Comment: I tried that, but It doesn't recognize view as a class :(

Comment: My IDE is Eclipse, and I'm sorry but I can't give it to you right now I'm not at home. I'll give it to you as soon as i can :)